# Conditional TextBlock formatting

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to both C# and XAML and I am making some sort of reading application.

So I need a `TextBlock` that word wraps if the title needs more than 1 row to fit. But when it becomes more that 2 rows to fit, wrap a `ScrollView` on it.

By doing this I could align the rest element tightly whenever it is either `1` or `2(max)` row height.

How do I achieve this in XAML or C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a `TextBox` instead of a `TextBlock`, it would be easier.  A `TextBox` supports scrolling and has a `LineCount` property that you can key off of.  So for example, I put the a few controls into a `StackPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="105,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184">
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Name="TextBox1"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then I had some code to update the text. When I hit 2 lines, I grew the `TextBox` and when I got to three lines, I added scrollbars:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text += "More Text";

    if (TextBox1.LineCount >= 2)
    {
        TextBox1.Height = 38; 
    }
    if (TextBox1.LineCount >= 3)
    {
        TextBox1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the TextBox an input controls. How am I suppose to deal with that?

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, `IsReadOnly="True"` might be enough.  Otherwise, there are lots of examples online on how to format a textbox in a variety of different ways.

Comment: So is it possible to format it exactly like TextBlock? And what about the performance?

Comment: @user1510539 I don't know your requirements for look and feel, but you can do all sorts of things in WPF to make a textbox look how you want.  A quick google search returns [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105982/visible-line-count-of-a-textblock) and [this](http://www.stievens-corner.be/index.php/10-wpf/18-make-textbox-look-like-textblock)

Comment: Thanks, as a substitute. That met my requirements:)