# Get TextBlock lines as separate strings WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, word-wrap

Is there any way to get TextBlock lines as separate strings after text wrapping? For example, if I have a TextBlock defined like this:

```
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
myTextBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
myTextBlock.Text = veryLongString;
```

Is it possible to get separate string for each row that is displayed in my TextBlock, which is created by TextWrapping.Wrap?

Comment: There's a reasonable looking implementation of a TextBox styled to behave like a TextBlock here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105982/visible-line-count-of-a-textblock, providing access to the LineCount property. Could be a practical approach.

Answer (score 0):

TextBlock has property called [`Inline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you could use that and access the strings one by one,

```
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in txtsample.Inlines)
            {
                if (line is LineBreak)
                    s.AppendLine();
                else if (line is Run)
                    s.Append(((Run)line).Text);
            }
            var text = s.ToString();
           }
```

Comment: I tried this but the probelm is that I always have only one line, which has the value of the whole "veryLongString" string, so I don't loop through InlinesCollection becouse it only have one value.

Comment: you should have linebrakes inorder to get the lines, otherwise try textbox which has lines property

Comment: Even if you set `Text` to a string with line breaks, the whole text goes into a single Run, which will be the only element of the `Inlines` collection.